# AWS ec2 user AMI istance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I'm new about the AWS world.
My problem is :
I've created a new user in my ec2 istance AMI (now I have two user : ec2-user and angelo-user). I want to restrict angelo-user to use the AWS-CLI.
It's possible ? How can I do?

Thanks in advance
Angelo

Comment: I presume that the user was created in an Amazon EC2 Windows or Linux instance. (FYI, the AMI simply loads the initial image of the boot disk -- no data is subsequently stored in the AMI.) What do you mean by "restrict angelo-user to use the AWS-CLI"? Are you saying that you don't want them to be able to use the credentials provided by an IAM Role that is assigned to the EC2 instance? Please provide more information, including an example to demonstrate what you'd like to see happen.

Comment: Ok. If I have an istance ec2 with Linux AMI configured with a AWS-CLI and the Linux OS has 2 users : 1) ec2-user   2) angelo-user I want to allow only first one user to use AWS-CLI. It's possibile?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could choose to only install the AWS CLI in one user's directory, but there is nothing stopping the other user from installing it too.

However, **the AWS CLI is useless without AWS credentials** that give permission to access AWS services. So, instead of thinking about "restricting the ability to run the AWS CLI", you should be thinking about how to "restrict access to AWS credentials" that allow the AWS CLI to use your AWS Account and services.

To give an example, think of **the front door to your house**. Anyone in the world can walk up to your door, but only people with the right key can gain access to your house. In the same way, anyone should be allowed to use the AWS CLI, but only people with the right credentials would actually be able to use your AWS Account.

Here is an approach that would achieve this goal:

- Install the AWS CLI and **let *anyone* on the instance use it**
- **Do NOT assign an IAM Role** to the EC2 instance (this way, *nobody* gets any credentials)
- For the user that you wish to permit access to AWS, you can run the `aws configure` command to store AWS credentials in that user's `~/.aws/credentials` file. This way, that user has AWS credentials but no other user has access to those credentials
- **Result:** That user can use AWS (and the AWS CLI) but the other users cannot